# Can a socket join more than one multicast group?

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I am implementing an application intends a socket to join more than multicast group?
So, Can a socket join more than one multicast group?

Comment: Could you elaborate why you don't want to just create more sockets?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subscribing to multiple multicast groups on one socket (Linux, C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243292/subscribing-to-multiple-multicast-groups-on-one-socket-linux-c)

Answer (score 0):

see this question and the answers provided therein: [Subscribing to multiple multicast groups on one socket (Linux, C)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9243292/1284631)

The longer answer is: yes, you can, using the appropriate setsockopt() call with the IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP option (quote: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9258030/1284631)

Comment: Thank you guys but If I bind on INADDR_ANY ??

Comment: @user1680544 It doesn't make any difference whether you bind on `INADDR_ANY`, unless some of the multicast groups require non-standard routine.

Comment: Err, sorry, routine => routing.