# how to configure eth0 as a sender udp port in tcl

Tags: tcl

I have a multiple network interfaces to my pc. I want to configure only eth0 as a udp sender for sending packets to other pc. How can we specify the interface name to be configured as udp sender. I have installed libudp-tcl, but not able to find the way  to do it. Can anybody tell me the exact way to do that.

Comment: Please reply on this. I need an urgent help. Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The udp package can't do what you want. As kostix mentioned you can always modify the udp package at the C level to expose the binding interface to tcl.

But there is an alternative work-around.

On Linux you can use iptables to restrict packets for specific ports to only go through specific interfaces. So, just open a UDP port of your choice (for example 9999) and then only allow packets from that port to go through eth0 and drop it from other interfaces.

For example, say your application uses UDP port 9999, then set up the following iptables rules:

```
# Accept udp packets from port 9999 for eth0
iptables -A OUTPUT -i eth0 -p udp --source-port 9999 -j ACCEPT
# Drop udp packets from port 9999 for all other interfaces
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --source-port 9999 -j DROP
```

Or you can do it in tcl using exec:

```
# Warning! Need to be root to do this:
set myPort 9999
exec /sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -i eth0 -p udp --source-port $myPort -j ACCEPT
exec /sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --source-port $myPort -j DROP
```

But always remember to delete your added rules before your program exits:

```
# Clearup iptables rules
exec /sbin/iptables -D OUTPUT -i eth0 -p udp --source-port $myPort -j ACCEPT
exec /sbin/iptables -D OUTPUT -p udp --source-port $myPort -j DROP
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will definitely try this. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

From what [I gather](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3062205/720999), to do what you want, you need to `bind(2)` to a specific IP address (one of those available on `eth0`) first, but the `udp` package [does not appear to support anything like this](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=udp&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=Debian+unstable+sid&format=html&locale=en).

So it looks like you need to patch the package yourself.  Tcl has excellent C API so it's not really hard if you're familiar with C.