# compute engine load balancer UDP/DNS responses dropped

Tags: load-balancing, google-compute-engine

Have been testing out GCE and the load balancing capabilities - however have been seeing some unexpected results.

The trial configuration involves 2 instances acting as DNS resolvers in a target pool with a 3rd test instance. There is also a http server running on the hosts.  No health check scripts have been added.

- DNS request to individual instance public IP  (from ANY) - OK
- HTTP request to individual instance public IP (from ANY) - OK
- HTTP request to load balance IP (from ANY) - OK
- DNS request to load balance IP (from an instance in the target pool) - OK
- DNS request to load balance IP (from an instance in the same network - but not in the target pool) - NOK
- DNS request to load balance IP (other) - NOK

I can see in the instance logs that the DNS request arrive for all cases and are distributed evenly - though the replies don't seem to get back to the originator.

The behavior seems unexpected.  I've played with the session affinity with similar results - though the default behavior is the most desired option.

Have hit a wall.  Are there some ideas to try?

Information on the setup:

```
$ gcutil listhttphealthchecks
+------+------+------+
| name | host | port |
+------+------+------+

$ gcutil listtargetpools
+----------+-------------+
| name     | region      |
+----------+-------------+
| dns-pool | us-central1 |
+----------+-------------+

$ gcutil listforwardingrules
+---------+-------------+-------------+
| name    | region      | ip          |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
| dns-tcp | us-central1 | 8.34.215.45 |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
| dns-udp | us-central1 | 8.34.215.45 |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
| http    | us-central1 | 8.34.215.45 |
+---------+-------------+-------------+

$ gcutil getforwardingrule dns-udp
+---------------+----------------------------------+
| name          | dns-udp                          |
| description   |                                  |
| creation-time | 2013-12-28T12:28:05.816-08:00    |
| region        | us-central1                      |
| ip            | 8.34.215.45                      |
| protocol      | UDP                              |
| port-range    | 53-53                            |
| target        | us-central1/targetPools/dns-pool |
+---------------+----------------------------------+

$ gcutil gettargetpool dns-pool
+------------------+-------------------------------+
| name             | dns-pool                      |
| description      |                               |
| creation-time    | 2013-12-28T11:48:08.896-08:00 |
| health-checks    |                               |
| session-affinity | NONE                          |
| failover-ratio   |                               |
| backup-pool      |                               |
| instances        | us-central1-a/instances/dns-1 |
|                  | us-central1-b/instances/dns-2 |
+------------------+-------------------------------+

[@dns-1 ~]$ curl "http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/network-interfaces/?recursive=true" -H "X-Google-Metadata-Request: True"
[{"accessConfigs":[{"externalIp":"162.222.178.116","type":"ONE_TO_ONE_NAT"}],"forwardedIps":["8.34.215.45"],"ip":"10.240.157.97","network":"projects/763472520840/networks/default"}]

[@dns-2 ~]$ curl "http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/network-interfaces/?recursive=true" -H "X-Google-Metadata-Request: True"
[{"accessConfigs":[{"externalIp":"8.34.215.162","type":"ONE_TO_ONE_NAT"}],"forwardedIps":["8.34.215.45"],"ip":"10.240.200.109","network":"projects/763472520840/networks/default"}]

$ gcutil getfirewall dns2
+---------------+------------------------------------+
| name          | dns2                               |
| description   | Allow the incoming service traffic |
| creation-time | 2013-12-28T10:35:18.185-08:00      |
| network       | default                            |
| source-ips    | 0.0.0.0/0                          |
| source-tags   |                                    |
| target-tags   |                                    |
| allowed       | tcp: 53                            |
| allowed       | udp: 53                            |
| allowed       | tcp: 80                            |
| allowed       | tcp: 443                           |
+---------------+------------------------------------+
```

The instances are CentOS and have their iptables firewalls disabled.

Reply from instance in target pool

```
@dns-1 ~]$ nslookup test 8.34.215.45 | grep answer
Non-authoritative answer:
@dns-1 ~]$
```

Reply from other instance in target pool

```
@dns-2 ~]$ nslookup test 8.34.215.45 | grep answer
Non-authoritative answer:
@dns-2 ~]$
```

No reply from instance *not* in the target pool on the load balanced IP.  However it gets a reply from all other interfaces

```
@dns-3 ~]$ nslookup test 8.34.215.45 | grep answer
@dns-3 ~]$ 
@dns-3 ~]$ nslookup test 8.34.215.162 | grep answer
Non-authoritative answer:
@dns-3 ~]$ nslookup test 10.240.200.109 | grep answer
Non-authoritative answer:
@dns-3 ~]$ nslookup test 10.240.157.97 | grep answer
Non-authoritative answer:
@dns-3 ~]$ nslookup test 162.222.178.116 | grep answer
Non-authoritative answer:
```

-- Update --
Added a health check so that the instances wouldn't be marked as UNHEALTHY.  However got the same result.

```
$ gcutil gettargetpoolhealth dns-pool
+-------------------------------+-------------+--------------+
| instance                      | ip          | health-state |
+-------------------------------+-------------+--------------+
| us-central1-a/instances/dns-1 | 8.34.215.45 | HEALTHY      |
+-------------------------------+-------------+--------------+
| us-central1-b/instances/dns-2 | 8.34.215.45 | HEALTHY      |
+-------------------------------+-------------+--------------+
```

-- Update --
Looks like the DNS service is not responding with the same IP that the request came in on.  This is for sure be the reason it doens't appear to be responding.

```
0.000000 162.222.178.130 -> 8.34.215.45  DNS 82 Standard query 0x5323  A test.internal
2.081868 10.240.157.97 -> 162.222.178.130 DNS 98 Standard query response 0x5323  A 54.122.122.227
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the DNS service is not responding with the same IP that the request came in on. This is for sure be the reason it doens't appear to be responding.

```
0.000000 162.222.178.130 -> 8.34.215.45  DNS 82 Standard query 0x5323  A test.internal
2.081868 10.240.157.97 -> 162.222.178.130 DNS 98 Standard query response 0x5323  A 54.122.122.227
```

Comment: Did you ever find a workaround for this? I am hitting this same issue right now. Thanks!

Comment: Yes.  I followed the technique described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062205/setting-the-source-ip-for-a-udp-socket and was able to get it working well.