# Send UDP datagram from a specified port WITHOUT binding

Tags: c++, winsock

I would like to send a UDP datagram from a specified port number WITHOUT binding (ex. when the port is already bound to another socket that I have no control over).

While I do appreciate the OS trying to keep everything nice and clean, and I cherish the `bind()` functionality, the question is as it is.

How to accomplish this with `WSASendTo()` or `WSASendMsg()`?

Comment: Calling `WSASendTo` on an unbound UDP socket will implicitly bind it. This behavior is not documented for `WSASendMsg`, but it likely behaves the same way. However, you said you have a socket that is *already bound*. In that case, you should be totally fine to call `WSASendTo` or `WSASendMsg` because, in the call, you will specify the destination, which will override whatever that socket has been previously bound to. Did you try it? Can you also provide us with more details about your *specific* situation? Are you trying to use the same socket across multiple processes? (That won't work.)

Comment: I just got to know that that WSASendTo implicitly binds the socket the moment you wrote it. Please do notice that I'm after setting the source port of the datagram and that I may not have control over (neither access to) the other socket which is already bound to port which I want to use.

Comment: Why do you care about the socket's *source* port? Isn't all you care about the *destination* port?

Comment: There are many benefits associated with knowing from which port UDP packets originate, including improved performance of NAT traversals through more efficient hole punching, or no need for hole-punching at all if source port is A priori known and can be configured on a NAT, anyone?

Comment: I've tried binding datagram port to source port address but then the API seems to ignore the REUSEADDR option... ehhh. windows?

Comment: according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062205/setting-the-source-ip-for-a-udp-socket windows does not support ipi_spec_dst for pktinfo  to be used by sendmsg thus seems like this CANNOT be done, on Microsoft Windows., without binding the socket.

Comment: @Vega4 `ipi_spec_dst` can't set a port number anyway, only an IP address (and as far as that goes, [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2ipdef/ns-ws2ipdef-in_pktinfo) suggests the source IP *can* be set for `WSASendMsg()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WSASendTo()` will use whichever source IP/Port the socket is currently bound to.  If the socket is not bound, `WSASendTo()` will perform an implicit binding first.

`WSASendMsg()` can use the `IN_PKTINFO`/`IN6_PKTINFO` structs to specify a **source IP** and **source interface**, but AFAIK the only way to specify a **source port** is through `bind()`.

Comment: ok, I will wait a short while and accept this answer, as that is in line what my research suggests as well.